# boton editar no funciona en formulario javascript

Tags: javascript, html

tengo un formulario, el cual no funciona el botón editar, este en vez de hacer la edición del registro, agrega una fila a la tabla, lo he imprimido por consola y sale que es undefined, esto se encuentra en la funcion Save() del JS, este siempre se va por el else :c

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/grid.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <link   href="css/grid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
    <script src="js/dialog.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <link   href="css/dialog.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
    <script src="js/draggable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/valida.js"></script>
    <link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css" media="screen" /> 


</head>
<body>

 <table border="1">
     <tr>
        <td>
            <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>Departamento originador:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="nomDepOri"></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>APE N°</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="apeN"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Centro de beneficio:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="centBene"></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Fecha de emisión</td>
                    <td width="80"><input type="date" id="fchFecha" readonly="readonly"  /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <hr>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>Sívase coordinar el retiro del siguiente material dado de baja</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td><button id="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Agregar</button></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>
             <table id="grid"></table>
         </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>
             <table id="button">
                 <tr>
                     <td><button>Guardar</button></td>
                 </tr>
             </table>
         </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>
              <div id="dialog" style="display:none">
                    <input type="hidden" id="ID">
                    <form name="formApe">

                    <table border="0" class="tablePopup">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="80">Cantidad</td>
                            <td width="160">Unidad de Medida</td>
                            <td>Condición</td>
                            <td>Activo Fijo</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>

                            <td><input type="text" id ="Cantidad" name="Cantidad"  class="solo-numero" maxlength="2" required></td>
                            <td>
                            <select id ="unidadMedida" required><option  value="" >Seleccione...</option>
                                              <option  value="Litros">Litros</option>
                                              <option  value="Kilos">Kilos</option>
                                              <option  value="Bulto">Bulto</option>
                                              <option  value="Lote">Lote</option>
                                              <option  value="Equipo">Equipo</option>
                                              <option  value="Piezas">Piezas</option>
                                              <option  value="Unidad">Unidad</option>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <select id ="condicion" required><option  value="">Seleccione...</option>
                                              <option  value="Bueno">Bueno</option>
                                              <option  value="Malo">Malo</option>
                                              <option  value="Regular">Regular</option>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <input type="radio"  name="activoFijo" value="Si" >Si
                            <input type="radio"  name="activoFijo" value="No" >No
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Descripción</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td scope="colgroup" colspan="4"><textarea cols="65" maxlength="1500" id="descripcion">ewdd</textarea></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                      <table border="0" class="tablaButton">
                          <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-default">Save</button></td>
                            <td width="80"><button type="button" id="btnCancel" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </form>
                </div>

         </td>
     </tr>

 </table>

</body>
</html>
```

**js**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var data, grid, dialog;
    data = [];

     dialog = $('#dialog').dialog({
        title: 'Agregar/Editar',
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        height:250,
        width:600,
        modal: true
    });
    function Edit(e) {
        $('#Item').val(e.data.id);
        $('#Cantidad').val(e.data.record.Cantidad);
        $('#unidadMedida').val(e.data.record.unidadMedida);
        $('#descripcion').val(e.data.record.descripcion);
        $('#condicion').val(e.data.record.condicion);
        $('#activoFijo').val(e.data.record.activoFijo);
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        $('#button').show();
    }
    function Delete(e) {
        if (confirm('¿esta seguro que desea eliminar este registro?')) {
            grid.removeRow(e.data.id);
            if(grid.count()!=0){
                $('#button').show();
            }else{
                $('#button').hide();
            }
        }
    }
    function Save() {

        var item=$('#Item').val();
        console.log(item);

        if (item) {
            console.log("entro a if");

            var id = parseInt($('#Item').val());
            grid.updateRow(id, { 'Item': id, 'Cantidad': $('#Cantidad').val(), 'unidadMedida': $('#unidadMedida').val(), 'descripcion' : $('#descripcion').val(), 'condicion' : $('#condicion').val(), 'activoFijo' : $('input[name="activoFijo"]:checked').val() });


        } else {
            console.log("entro a else");
            grid.addRow({ 'Item': grid.count() + 1, 'Cantidad': $('#Cantidad').val(), 'unidadMedida': $('#unidadMedida').val(), 'descripcion' : $('#descripcion').val(), 'condicion' : $('#condicion').val(), 'activoFijo' : $('input[name="activoFijo"]:checked').val()});
        }
        dialog.close();
        $('#button').show();
    }

    grid = $('#grid').grid({
        dataSource: data,
        columns: [
            { field: 'Item', width: 32 },
            { field: 'Cantidad' },
            { field: 'unidadMedida', title: 'Unidad de Medida' },
            { field: 'descripcion', title: 'Descripcion' },
            { field: 'condicion', title: 'Condicion'},
            { field: 'activoFijo', title: 'Activo Fijo (si-no)'},
            { width: 50, tmpl: '<a href="#"><img src="img/editar.png"></a>', align: 'center', events: { 'click': Edit } },
            { width: 50, tmpl: '<a href="#"><img src="img/eliminar.png"></a>', align: 'center', events: { 'click': Delete } }
        ]
 });

    $('#btnAdd').on('click', function () {
        $('#Item').val('');
        $('#Cantidad').val('');
        $('#unidadMedida').val('');
        $('#descripcion').val('');
        $('#condicion').val('');
        $('#activoFijo').val('');
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    });


    $('#btnSave').on('click', function(){
        if(comprobarCamposRequired()){
            Save();
        }else{
            alert("llene todos los campos");
        }

    } );
   // $('#btnSave').on('click', comprobarCamposRequired);
    $('#btnCancel').on('click', function(){

        dialog.dialog("close");
    });

     $('.solo-numero').keyup(function (){
            this.value = (this.value + '').replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
          });

     $(function($){
                $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
                    closeText:'Cerrar',
                    currentText:'Hoy',
                    monthNames:['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
                    monthNamesShort:['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr', 'May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep', 'Oct','Nov','Dic'],
                    dayNames:['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
                    dayNamesShort:['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mié','Juv','Vie','Sáb'],
                    dayNamesMin:['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','Sá'],
                    weekHeader:'Sm',
                    dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy',
                    firstDay:1,
                    isRTL:false,
                    showMonthAfterYear:false,
                    yearSuffix:''
                };
        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);  

    });

             $("#fchFecha").datepicker({
                  changeMonth: true,
                  changeYear: true,
                  showOn: "button",
                  buttonImage: "img/calendar.gif",
                  buttonImageOnly: true,
                  showAnim: "drop",
                  buttonText: "Selecione una Fecha"
    });
             $('#button').hide();

     function comprobarCamposRequired(){
            var correcto=true;
            var campos=$('input[type="text"]:required');
            var select=$('select:required');

            $(campos).each(function() {
                if($(this).val()==''){
                    correcto=false;
                    $(this).addClass('error');
                }       
        });

    $(select).each(function() {
            if($(this).val()==''){
                correcto=false;
                $(this).addClass('error');
            }
        });
    return correcto;

    }

    $('input[type="text"]:required').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('error');
    });



    var hoy = new Date();
            dia = hoy.getDate();
            mes = ((hoy.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? '0' : '') + (hoy.getMonth() + 1);
           anio = hoy.getFullYear();
   fecha_actual = String(dia+"/"+mes+"/"+anio);
 $("#fchFecha").val(fecha_actual);


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obtienes `undefined` porque en ningún lado lo has definido, en el código HTML<sup>1</sup> no figura. Crea:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="Item">
```

y prueba.

---

**Actualización**

Cambia

```html
<input type="hidden" id="ID">
```

por

```html
<input type="hidden" id="Item">
```

---

*Notas*

1. O más exactamente, en el DOM. Véase en Wikipedia [*Document Object Model*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model).

Answer (score 1):

Verifica el codigo con el inspector de Chrome si lo usas, y verifica que exista el elemento con el id Item, si es asi verifica que no este mas de una vez, si esta mas de una vez esto puede generarte ese error

Comment: Verifique el codigo y usas un plugin para que te autogenere la tabla, es por eso que en el html no encontre el tan mentado Item